# Java Save List to Prefs

Tags: java, list

I am working on a project and have an observablelist which populates a JavaFX table. This works great, but I am trying to save the contents of this table to a preferences file using the java.util.prefs API. I can save strings, int's etc... but I am not sure how to save a list.

I have `ObservableList<Account> dataList` which I then add account info to. This is then used to populate the JavaFX table. Is there a way to store dataList to prefs without iterating through and saving it as one long string?

My first approach was to iterate through, adding a special char in between each entry, so that I could then split the string once loaded from prefs at a later time.

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend you to transform this list in a JSON string. With any JSON api. Consider [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) It would be simple enough like you need.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the XML encoder:

```
XMLEncoder e = new XMLEncoder(
    new BufferedOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream("Test.xml")));
e.writeObject(dataList);
e.close();
```

Or consider serialization ([tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html)):

```
 FileOutputStream fileOut =
 new FileOutputStream("/tmp/accounts.dat");
 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
 out.writeObject( dataList );
 out.close();
```

You'll need to make certain your list implements Serializable (most built-in Java objects do) and your Account class will likely need to implement Serializable as well.

Comment: So you would suggest using XML encoder instead of prefs? Thanks. I'll give it a go

Comment: Yes, prefs seem an odd choice to me.  They're basically maps, you wouldn't store a list as one.

Comment: Okay thanks. I just looked in to saving settings and prefs was the most common answer. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried your second solution but no luck. I am getting "Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper" I have put "implaments serializable" in my Account class, but I still get this error

Answer (score 0):

You might consider Serializing the list ? :o

Like in this tutorial http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=57

Your Account object would need to implements Serializable.